# How to get key only with openssl command?

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

How can I just retrieve the key value only with openssl command below?

`$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1`

Output:

```
salt=9EFF5E41E21EA17F
key=D0F15A0E51C29FA9E7AC1B63DC4585D3
iv =F0090A64ADB51DE25A28151B0C55DAEA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without the salt value, isn't that pretty useless? Since the key depends on both the password and the salt, and the salt's random, the key is effectively just a random hex sequence.

Comment: Use the `-nosalt` option to suppress the use of a salt in the key derivation. But consider that this is **not** recommended. Note that `sha1` is also **not** recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` and `sed` in pipes:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1 | grep key | sed 's/.*=//'
```

The `grep` command filters out lines without "key".
The `sed` command replaces all characters from the start up to and including the `=` with nothing (deleting them).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-nosalt` option to suppress the use of a salt in the key derivation. But consider that this is **not** recommended. Note that this key derivation method is also **not** recommended, especially with `sha1`.

Anyway, with `awk`:

```sh
$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -k secret -P -md sha1 |
  awk -F= '$1 == "key" {print $2}'
2BB80D537B1DA3E38BD30361AA855686
```